# Tabs in Fragment, but layout doesnt show up

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tabs

Since friday im trying to create 3 tabs in one class (FragmentCV.class) which extends fragment.

Now, i thought i figured it out but its still not working right

The app doesnt crash and i also dont get any error/warning messages.

When i try to open the FragmentCV.java, it should show me the layout with those 3 tabs.

But somehow i see nothing in there. Its empty but in the XML file i can see those tabs.

FragmentCV.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentCV extends Fragment {

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;


    public FragmentCV() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cv, container, false);

        mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.fragment1);

        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("personal Profile").setIndicator("Personal Profile", null),
                FragmentCVpage1.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("education").setIndicator("Education", null),
                Fragment_CVpage2.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("bla").setIndicator("Bla", null),
                FragmentCVpage3.class, null);

        return mTabHost;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mTabHost = null;
    }
}
```

fragment_cv.XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabHost
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </TabWidget>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: Maybe i shall say, im using a "Navigation Drawer Layout" class.

With the "Navigation Drawer" im calling the "FragmentCV.java Fragment.

**So when i start the app:**

1. The MainActivity.java (Navigation Drawer layout) opens. It contains a "drawer", "toolbar" and one Fragment called "content_main.xml"
2. i open the drawer and press on one button to call the "FragmentCV.java"
3. Now i should see the "fragment_cv.xml" with the 3 tabs, BUT i still see the "content_main.xml" layout. So it seems like the "fragment_cv.xml" doesnt show up